# C# with SharpZipLib - Compatibility of SharpZipLib with Winzip and XP?

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I am using the [CSharpZipLib](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx) library to automatically zip some files.  The problem is that the resulting zip file doesn't work with Winzip (version 8.1) or XP's compressed folders.
It does work with 7zip.

Winzip gives an error that **this file is not in the standard Zip 2.0 format**.

Is there a parameter that I can change that would get the library to compress in a Winzip/XP compatible format?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set this in your ZipOutputStream:

```
 UseZip64 = ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.UseZip64.Off
```

Zip64 is not compatible with the Windows XP compressed folders utility or with WinZip.

Edit: apparently the API has changed since the version I'm using, the property is now an enum rather than a Boolean value.

Comment: I tried s.UseZip64 = false but VS2008 complains

Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.UseZip64'?

Comment: Need to use s.UseZip64 = UseZip64.Off

Comment: Found this answer and while it helped, I also had to remove the CRC from the entries as well.