# How to create a zip file over 7 GB in C# using SharpZipLib?

Tags: c#, zip

I want to create a zip file in C# that will include almost 8 GB of data. I am using the following code:

```
using (var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(System.IO.File.Create(outPath)))
{
    zipStream.SetLevel(9); // 0-9, 9 being the highest level of compression

    var buffer = new byte[1024*1024];

    foreach (var file in filenames)
    {
        var entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file)) { DateTime = DateTime.Now };

        zipStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

        var bufferSize = BufferedSize;
        using (var fs = new BufferedStream(System.IO.File.OpenRead(file), bufferSize))
        {
            int sourceBytes;
            do
            {
                 sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                 zipStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
             } while (sourceBytes > 0);
         }
     }

     zipStream.Finish();
     zipStream.Close();
 }
```

This code works for small files under 1 GB, but it throws an exception when the data reaches 7-8 GB.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is a valid question, isnt it?

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier Perhaps because the question doesn't include any information about the exception?

Comment: A valid question doesn't make it a good question, FWIW.

Comment: Your title should reflect that you'are not just searching for how to zip in general, but that you have a specific problem. Something like "Trouble zipping files over 7Go in C#" would be far more better. I guess that why you get down vote ;)

Comment: And because you didn't give the error message/exception.

Comment: To the OP: You're using SharpZipLib, correct? That's the library that includes `ZipOutputStream`, so you should specify that if you're not using the standard C# libraries.

Comment: To the OP, was my answer helpful at all?

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, the actual exception would have helped a lot in answering this. However, if you want an easier way to create zip-files I would suggest you try the DotNetZip-library available at http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/. I know it has support for Zip64 (ie larger entries then 4.2gb and more then 65535 entries) so it might be able to solve your problem. It is also a lot easer to use then working with filestreams and bytearrays yourself.

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()) {
    zip.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.Always;
    zip.BufferSize = 65536*8; // Set the buffersize to 512k for better efficiency with large files

    foreach (var file in filenames) {
        zip.AddFile(file);
    }
    zip.Save(outpath);
}
```

Comment: Can u tell me one thing,sir....if i'm using your code..for handle the large File(4 gb)...it doesn't reduce the size of file(i.e. created zip file) ...it will shows 4gb as rar file..

Comment: Yes this doesn't affect the size of the output, it just allows the size to be larger than ~4.2gb. If you want to make even smaller files you should look into some other compression (though this will probably also be a lot slower to compress).

Answer (score 2):

You're using SharpZipLib, correct? I'm not sure if this is a valid solution because I don't know what exception it throws, but based on [this post](http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/12/windows-xp-unzip-errors-with.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422520/c-sharp-with-sharpziplib-compatibility-of-sharpziplib-with-winzip-and-xp), it may be a problem with `Zip64`. Either enable it using code similar to this (from the second linked post):

```
UseZip64 = ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.UseZip64.Off
```

or, based on the first post, specify the size of the archive when you create it, which should automatically take care of the `Zip64` problem. Sample code directly from the first linked post:

```
using (ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(zipFilePath)))
{
 //Compression level 0-9 (9 is highest)
 zipStream.SetLevel(GetCompressionLevel());

 //Add an entry to our zip file
 ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath));
 entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
 /* 
 * By specifying a size, SharpZipLib will turn on/off UseZip64 based on the file sizes. If Zip64 is ON
 * some legacy zip utilities (ie. Windows XP) who can't read Zip64 will be unable to unpack the archive.
 * If Zip64 is OFF, zip archives will be unable to support files larger than 4GB.
 */
 entry.Size = new FileInfo(sourceFilePath).Length;
 zipStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

 byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
 int byteCount = 0;

 using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFilePath))
 {
     byteCount = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     while (byteCount > 0)
     {
         zipStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
         byteCount = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     }
 }
}
```