# Can we ZIP/Unzip files larger than 4GB using .Net 4.5 libraries?

Tags: compression, zip, unzip

We have an original zip library which uses the SharpZipLib and .NET 2.0. We need to research what is now possible in .NET 4.5 using System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.

Should we use .NET 4.5 libraries or use a 3rd party open source library?
Also, we need to be able to zip/unzip files larger than 4GB.
Samples, blogs, any help is welcomed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4GB is the maximum addressible size for a 32-bit pointer, hence it will not work for larger file. But you can try Zip64 which will work for larger files. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422520/c-sharp-with-sharpziplib-compatibility-of-sharpziplib-with-winzip-and-xp) post might help you.

Hope this will help!

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: weird... I just used that library and it compressed a > 4GB just fine, with or without the UseZip64. Is it because my Windows is 64 bits?

Comment: Theoretically a 64-bit architecture can address 16.8 million terabytes of memory, [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) post might give you  more detail about addressible size for 64 bit machine. Thanks Suresh

Answer (score 2):

3rd party.  Use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).  It supports the Zip64 format.